# canvas - Substract shape from a clipped canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clip

I want to clip an annulus (i.e. ring) from an image via javascripts canvas.
I already have an approach but i think its too inelegant (and I really dont understand why this works, and why it doesnt just result in a smaller circle).

[see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InsOp/o68Lrsb8/)

```
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 500, 500);

    //crop outer circle
    context2.beginPath();
    context2.arc(250, 250, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context2.closePath();
    context2.clip();

    //draw circle
    context2.drawImage(canvas,0,0);

    //crop inner circle
    context2.beginPath();
    context2.arc(250, 250, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context2.closePath();
    context2.clip();

    //clear context 2
    context2.clearRect(0,0,500,500)

    // finally draw annulus
    context2.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't get the objective. Are you not satisfied drawing canvas in canvas?

Comment: @TheProHands i want to clip a shape out of an already clipped shape (in photoshop you would call it "substract from selection") without the extra step of drawing a temporary image to the second canvas. I want a solution in one step (or at least want my solution to be explained)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does work because clipping areas called by `clip` method do stack.

IMO, this is indeed not the best way to do it, as you definitely need to call `ctx.save();` before clipping and `ctx.restore()` afterward, which are really heavy methods.

My preferred way is to use [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) :

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {

  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 500, 500);
  // keep only the outer circle
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
  // remove the inner one
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
  // reset gCO
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

};
imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: perfect, thats what i searched. If you want, you may edit my question (as well as the title into a more understanding one) as I think that other users may find this useful, too.

Comment: @InsOp, not sure either what would be a best title for this question... Anyway, glad it helped. Ps: other gCOs and order could achieve the same result, have fun with it ;-)